# finding a word in a string

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I want to find word `abc` in a string (I only want the exact word abc, not words that contain abc) but I get the following error:

```
echo "asjhdhahsjdajhsdabcasjdhas abc asdasdabc" | grep <abc>
```

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `-o` (show the matched string only) and `-w` (match pattern as a whole word only)

```
$ echo "asjhdhahsjdajhsdabcasjdhas abc asdasdabc" | grep -ow abc
abc
```

Thanks to steeldriver for explaining how you can actually use the `<` and `>` instead of `-w` to indicate word boundaries. They should be `\<` and `\>` but the backslashes have to be quoted to be passed to grep as well as the `<` symbols, since they also have special meaning to the shell. So strong-quote the expression like this:

```
echo "asjhdhahsjdajhsdabcasjdhas abc asdasdabc" | grep -o '\<abc\>'
```

or go crazy with the backslashes:

```
echo "asjhdhahsjdajhsdabcasjdhas abc asdasdabc" | grep -o \\\<abc\\\>
```

Comment: I think the OP was probably trying to use the `\<` and `\>` GNU word boundaries i.e. `grep '\<abc\>'` (equivalent to your `-w` flag - or POSIX `'\babc\b'`)

Comment: Thanks, yeah that works. As @steeldriver has mentioned I was trying to use word boundries as it is suggested in here: http://www.linuxnix.com/regular-expressions-linux-i/

Comment: @steeldriver indeed, I was confused by how I don't get any output when I tried escaping them... hmm!

Comment: @Zanna I think it should work if you escape both the backslashes and >,< chars i.e. `\\\<abc\\\>`